# Why does std::distance return zero?

Tags: c++

In the code below I try to calculate the distance between two iterators. The iterators start at the same position and I advance one three times, so I feel like the distance between them should be three, but I always get 0. Why?

```
using namespace std;

stringstream strstream{"Hello world"};
            
auto b = istream_iterator<char>{strstream};
auto e = istream_iterator<char>{strstream};

++e;
++e;
++e;
            
cout << "distance: " << distance(b,e) << endl;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because input iterators only guarantee a single pass.  The following is from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator) about the `operator++` of an input iterator:

> `++r`
>
> [...]
>
> Postcondition: Any copies of the previous value of r are no longer required to be either dereferenceable or to be in the domain of ==.

So, after `++e`, `b` no longer has any guarantee on its value or if it is even usable.

Comment: Note that while input iterators in general only provide single-pass guarantees, `b` *could* still be usable depending on the exact iterator type. But `istream_iterator` *explicitly* says that it isn't.

Comment: @NicolBolas Do you have a source for that?  I can't find anything [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) about that though I could just be missing it.

Comment: Actually, it seems to be well-defined. `istream_iterator` equality is based on whether the two iterators point to the same stream. Incrementing and getting values is based on what stream they point to, as is copying. So it's well-defined... that both iterators point to the same place. And therefore, `distance` *must* be zero.

Comment: @NicolBolas  "therefore, `distance`  *must* be zero"  - That's worth an answer.

Comment: @NicolBolas I stumbled across the same reference and posted an answer.  I did not see your comment and was not trying to steal your thunder!

Answer (score 7):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator/operator_cmp):

> Two [istream] iterators are equal if both of them are end-of-stream iterators or **both of them refer to the same stream**.

Because your two stream iterators refer to the same stream, **they are equal**.  It does not matter that you advanced one of them.

Since they are equal, there is `0` distance between them.

Answer (score 1):

`b` and `e` are stream iterators, they refer the stream with its read position, perform one char read from the input stream and store the read char. They are not reachable from each other, they are equal and refer a stream with its stream read position.

```
stringstream strstream{"Hello world"};

auto b = istream_iterator<char>{strstream};
cout << "char: " << *b << endl;  // char: H

auto e = istream_iterator<char>{strstream};
cout << "char: " << *e << endl;  // char: e
```

'H' and 'e' are read from the stream, any of `++e` or `++b` will read the next chars:

```
++b;
cout << "char: " << *b << endl;  // char: l - NOT char: e
++e;
++e;
cout << "char: " << *b << endl;  // char: o - NOT char: e
```